# Azure Site Recovery Replicated VMs no longer bootable

Tags: hyper-v, azure-vm

The last time we did a fail-over test in January, everything worked as expected.  Today, when doing the same test 5 of my 6 VMs will no longer boot.

2 of them simply display a black screen with a blinking cursor when I view them in Boot Diagnostics, 3 of them display non system disk or disk errors.  I've attempted restarting, re-deploying and winding down and re testing from a older RPO (both app and crash consistent ones.)  No success and no useful messages to work with.

It's a mix of OS's; 2012R2, and 2016. All replicated from Windows Server Hyper-V 2016.

Again, this worked 3 months ago, no errors in replication health, and other than windows updates, no changes to the servers/applications on them.

Did a recent windows update have a known issue with Azure replication or something - anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR - rinse and repeat.  Tried again next week and it worked.

I came back a week later and repeated process and same servers all come up this time...  No changes.  Presumably an update of some sort as I tried multiple restore points going back 12 hours before I posted my question...